# Xcode After Localization, I can't add things from my Storyboard

Tags: localization, ios-simulator, xcode4.5, uistoryboard

I was playing around with Localization.strings because of a strange search result with swedish  characters, so I read somewhere that Localisation was the thing to do. I had it wrong so I removed the file I just made.

Now the problem is, if I add a new object in the storyboard, it doesnt show up in the simulator. What's is wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just had the same problem, looks like when there's a storyboard file change you might need to delete the application from the device to force the use of the right version.

Hope this helps!

Best